# How to filter distance between dynamic user location and shops within a certain distance (2km)

Tags: django, filter, geolocation, distance

I want to filter shops within a certain distance from dynamic user location from html5. I want to fetch user location from html5 geolocation and make a distance filter in django. My problem is saving the the user location to django model. I get `TypeError: Distance function requires a geometric argument in position 2.` when trying to filter shops based on the model's `user_location'.

models.py:

```
class UserProfile(geo_models.Model):
    username = geo_models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=geo_models.CASCADE)
    recorded_at = geo_models.DateTimeField()  # time recorded on phone
    created_at = geo_models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)  # time saved on db
    user_location =  geo_models.PointField()
    accuracy = geo_models.IntegerField() # meters, rounded up
    # meters, rounded more info... IP, phone type, phone id, session id, app version etc.
    phone_number = geo_models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True) #  change the field to watever works for you
    email = geo_models.EmailField()
    first_name = geo_models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True)
    last_name = geo_models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    
   

#  This will auto create a profile of user with blank phone number that can be updated later.
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
user_loc = UserProfile().user_location
queryset = Apartment.objects.annotate(distance=D('location',user_loc)).order_by('distance')[0:6]
```

views.py:

```
class CreateUserLocation(CreateView):
    model = UserLocation
    fields = ['user','user_location']
    template_name = 'rent_app/geolocate.html'
    success_url = '/thanks/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        return super(CreateUserLocation).form_valid(form)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        profile = self.get_object()
        user_loc = request.POST.get("user_location")
        
        if user_loc is None:
            return HttpResponse()

        profile.save()

        return HttpResponse()
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var collection = {{ object_list|geojsonfeature:"popupContent"|safe }};
  console.log(collection);
  function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
      layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.popupContent);
    }
  }

  function ourfunction(map, options) {
    
    map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16});
    map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);

    function onLocationFound(e) {
    var radius = e.accuracy;
    var pos = e.latlng;

    L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)
        .bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point").openPopup();

    L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
}
        function onLocationError(e) {
            alert(e.message);
        }

        map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);
            
    L.geoJson(collection, {onEachFeature: onEachFeature}).addTo(map);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: from where `geo_models` come from...  I familiar with from `django.contrib.gis.db` import models and their fields . Althought the `user_loc` -> `user_location` it seems is not the type recognized by your `distance` lookup. Sorry not help, but it seems a litle odd to me.

Comment: I am importing gis models as geo_models. @CarlosLeite

Comment: and the database ? is it postgis ?    ...  I must check, but may you must covert the type ti "metric" ...  i'll let you know

Comment: It is postgis. Yes, It is not recognized, it gives " geometric object expected" error for the user_location. I could not manage to save the user location from javascript ajax call to the django database and measure the distance between the apartments and user location or filter apartments within a certain radius.

Comment: put the JS code you are using to send the location. Is it a tuple or similar in text ? kml point ?

Comment: @CarlosLeite Added js code.